# Changing views layout parameters on runtime

Tags: android

I have a `TabHost`, in one of it's `Activity` (which is first tab in `TabHost`). I have to change layout parameters for some `Views` in this activity, I used to this in `onWindowFocusChanged` method and it worked, but this method is not invoked when I use method `tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab)` and then click on this Activity's tab. I tried to use `ViewTreeObserver` to get layout parameters and change them, but layouts height is 0. When can I change the View's parameters or can I manually invoke `onWindowFocusChanged`?

In this way I used `VTO`

```
    final ViewPager mainLayout = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewPager slidingImages = ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager));
            int h = slidingImages.getHeight();
            mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                    this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `ViewTreeObserver` should do the trick, show us the way which you tried.

Comment: @Android-Developer I added the code, I used to get another layouts this view_pager I picked just for example

Comment: why you declare your ViewPager again in your `onGlobalLayout` ?

Comment: @Android-Developer I was changing mainLayout (setting another views) and I'm interested in the height of that ViewPager, not declaring it does not change anything

Comment: So if you call `int h = mainLayout.getHeight();` you get always 0?

Comment: @Android-Developer If I use `setCurrentTab` and set this activity to display on screen it returns correct height, but when I set another tab to display this method is invoked but the value is 0

Comment: are you settings adapter to your view pager?

Comment: @Android-Developer yes, but the height for another child views in the parent of that viewPager are all 0

Comment: try to remove `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` if viewpager's height is bigger than 0. give some more information about what you want to achieve getting viewpager's height?

Comment: I used this `ViewTreeObserver` in `onCreate` method, now I moved it in `onResume` and I'm getting correct height.